# typeerror: bool object not callable - jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
   a = int(input())
   b = int(input())
     if a>b:
         print(a)
         print("help")
```

I keep getting the type error while running the code.

Comment: Your code is not indented properly.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine when pasted and correctly indented. Do you by any chance define an `input`/`int`/`print` variable somewhere earlier in the code?

Comment: a = int(input())
b = int(input())
if a>b:
    print(a)
    print("help")     its still saying there is an error at line 4

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with following, you need to be careful with the spaces used for your if statement. I also put text to your input to make it clear.

```
a = int(input("Press a number: "))
b = int(input("Press second number: "))

if a>b:
    print(a)
    print("help")
```

Output:

```
Press a number: 5
Press second number: 3
5
help
```